# How to add gradient background to text (multiple lines)

Tags: css, text, background

I found this jsfiddle on the internet. Does anyone of you know how I can change the background color from white into a gradient color? The gradient color should "restart" on each new line. Please see desired wish on "example 2" in this image: http://www.managers.dk/css-text-background.jpg

http://jsfiddle.net/omgmog/g3MQf/

```
h1 { width:480px; font:bold 36px sans-serif; letter-spacing:-1px; color:#000; }

h1 { 
background: #fff; 
display:inline; 
white-space: pre-line; 
position: relative; 
padding: 9px 0; 
line-height: 54px;
-moz-box-shadow: -20px 0 0 #fff, 20px 0 0 #fff;
-webkit-box-shadow: -20px 0 0 #fff, 20px 0 0 #fff;
box-shadow: -20px 0 0 #fff, 20px 0 0 #fff;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Comment: If you are happy with a vertical gradient, too, just use `linear-gradient`: http://jsfiddle.net/g3MQf/71/

Comment: not good enough to be an answer, but maybe some compromise http://jsfiddle.net/g3MQf/74/ mix-blend-mode where browsers understands it :(

Comment: Hey guys please check my updated answer without using span.

Answer (score 4):

I don't believe there is a way to accomplish what you are looking for in plain CSS since there is no "new line" selector. The only way to do it is to explicitly define each new line by wrapping the text into a span element.

```css
body
{
    padding:50px;
    background:#fff;
}
h1
{
    width:480px;
    font:bold 36px sans-serif;
    letter-spacing:-1px;
    color:#000;
    display:inline; 
    white-space: pre-line; 
    position: relative; 
    padding: 9px 0; 
    line-height: 54px;
}
h1 span
{
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(148,199,247,1) 0%, rgba(32,124,229,1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(left top, right top, color-stop(0%, rgba(148,199,247,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(32,124,229,1)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(148,199,247,1) 0%, rgba(32,124,229,1) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(148,199,247,1) 0%, rgba(32,124,229,1) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(148,199,247,1) 0%, rgba(32,124,229,1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(148,199,247,1) 0%, rgba(32,124,229,1) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#94c7f7', endColorstr='#207ce5', GradientType=1 );
}

header
{
    width: 550px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <h1>
      <span>Some dynamic HTML text on</span>
      <span>several lines with a background</span>
      <span>that suits well and some margins</span>
      <span>around it.</span>
    </h1>
  </header>
</body>
```

Comment: it only works if you wrap each pieces into spans, where white-space was suppose to keep text indentation and do this :) .

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/g3MQf/73/ This doesn't need spans, but as soon as the text changes, the box shadow is distorted :(

Comment: If you set the line-height to a higher value it will look fine the way you did it.

Comment: mix-blend-mode might help for a few browsers : http://jsfiddle.net/g3MQf/74/ this is the closest i think of without extra tags, but as commented elsewhere here, inline-behavior doesnt allow to restart a bg at beggining of each lines, it only spray background into the lines ...

Answer (score 2):

Please check my updated answer.
I have added `background-attachment:fixed;` to get the desired output.

```css
h1 { width:480px; font:bold 28px sans-serif; letter-spacing:-1px; color:#fff; 
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #085d9d 0%, #92d5ff 100%);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #085d9d 0%, #92d5ff 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #085d9d 0%, #92d5ff 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to right, #085d9d 0%, #92d5ff 100%); 
background-attachment:fixed;
display: inline;
line-height: 50px;
padding: 7px 3px;
white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

```html
    <h1>Some dynamic HTML text on several lines with a background that suits well and some margins around it.</h1>
```

Comment: Similar answer is below ;)

Comment: and : it only works if you wrap each pieces into spans, where white-space was suppose to keep text indentation and do this :) .

Comment: @phpheini yes i have posted similar answer, but in my answer i have modifed linear-gradient style according to his need.

Comment: Styling of linear-gradient

Comment: @GCyrillus now you can check my updated answer which is without span.

Comment: @phpheini Check my updated answer, without span and your's with span.

Comment: @SunilGehlot The problem is that it doesn't work the way the op wants it since it creates one background image for the whole h1 element. So the last text "around it" has no real gradient :-/

Comment: @SunilGehlot your update shows exactly the issue the op runs in ;)

Comment: this is genius. i have just stumbled across this article from 2021 that achieves same thing in a million times more complicated approach, that works only with white background and text. and this answer is from 2016 and just OWNS it lol

Answer (score 1):

If you're unfamiliar with gradients there are tools out there that will help you do it more visually. One such tool is http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ which will allow you to visually build your gradient, then click a button to copy that code to be pasted into your CSS file. It will provide you with browser safe options for most of the main browsers. simply add it to your background CSS code and it should produce the result you requested.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
    -webkit-box-decoration-break:clone;
```

to your css and it will restart the gradient in every line.